# Delete a File from the apps private storage directory - Android

Tags: file-io, android-file, android

I am having a bit of trouble trying to delete a file from the applications private storage directory that I have programmatically created and compressed.

The problem I am facing is that it's not recognising that the file exists when I call *file.exists()*, and so it will not delete the file.

This is the code I'm using to delete the file

```
public static void deleteImageFromPrivateArea( final String fileUri )
  {
    final File file;
    boolean isFileDeleted;
    if ( isFilePathPrefixPresent( fileUri ) )
    {//file name checking
      file = new File( fileUri );
    }
    else
    {
      file = new File( "file://" + fileUri );
    }

    if ( file.exists() )
    {
      isFileDeleted = file.delete();
      if ( ! isFileDeleted )
      {
        throw new IllegalStateException( "File was not deleted" );
      }
    }
  }
```

1. To clear things up, I know that the fileUri I'm passing through is the location of a file that currently exists. I have checked with a filemanager app.
2. I have the permissions set up in the manifests xml.
3. What I believe is happening is that this code is getting the path of the currently existing file, and setting up a new file but not writing the data to it thus this new file does not exist in android.

So what I think I need to do is get the existing file (maybe not in the form of a Uri, but the actual file) and then call .delete() as then the file would exist.

Or

After setting up this new file with the fileUri, write the data to it using an OutputfileStream - this would not be my preferred method though.

-but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 2):

would be easier just to pass the filename as a parameter then do

```
 File mydir = getFilesDir(); //get your internal directory
 File myFile = new File(mydir, filename);
 myFile.delete();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! This got me close to what I needed. Instead of using getFilesDir() I used _getExternalFilesDir( Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES )_

Answer (score 1):

With help from BradR I found the best solution.

1. I used *getExternalFilesDir( Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES )* to get the pictures 2. directory in the applications private storage area.
2. Created a new file with the given imageUri and then used this to get the filename of the file.
3. Reinitialized the File to create a new file using the *ExternalFilesDir* and *filename*
4. Check that the file exists and delete it.

#

```
  public static void deleteImageFromPrivateArea( final Context context, final String imageUri )
  {
    String filename;
    File file;
    final File dir = context.getExternalFilesDir( Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES );

    if ( isFilePathPrefixPresent( imageUri ) )
    {
      file = new File( imageUri );
    }
    else
    {
      file = new File( "file://" + imageUri );
    }

    filename = file.getName();
    file = new File( dir, filename );

    if ( file.exists() )
    {
      try
      {
        file.delete();
      }
      catch ( Exception e )
      {
        throw new IllegalStateException( "File wasn't deleted" );
      }
    }
    else
    {
      throw new IllegalStateException( "File was doesn't exist" );
    }
  }
```